# Is this the best I can do with my SQL Server query that pulls data from multiple table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I would like to think of myself as a decent SQL Server programmer but this query always stumps me. I'm sure there is a much better way to query this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    database_name,
    CASE 
        WHEN ((SELECT MAX(1) FROM dbo.column_list WHERE column_list IS NOT NULL and database_id = d.database_id) = 1 
                OR (SELECT MAX(1) FROM dbo.table_list WHERE table_list IS NOT NULL and database_id = d.database_id) = 1) 
            THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 
    END AS 'has_definition'
FROM dbo.database_list d;
```

I have 3 tables database_list, table_list and a column_list. I'm trying to query for a given database in the database list to see if any of the underlying table or column has definitions in them. This query works now and returns a unique list of databases and a has_definition but this seems wrong to me.

Any thoughts would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try this version instead:

```
SELECT database_name,
    CASE WHEN EXISTS 
    (
      SELECT 1 FROM dbo.column_list 
         WHERE column_list IS NOT NULL and database_id = d.database_id
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 1 FROM dbo.table_list 
         WHERE table_list IS NOT NULL and database_id = d.database_id
    ) 
            THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 
    END AS [has_definition]
FROM dbo.database_list AS d;
```

And maybe compare it to this:

```
SELECT database_name,
    CASE WHEN EXISTS 
    (
      SELECT 1 FROM dbo.column_list 
         WHERE column_list IS NOT NULL and database_id = d.database_id
    ) 
    OR EXISTS
    (
      SELECT 1 FROM dbo.table_list 
         WHERE table_list IS NOT NULL and database_id = d.database_id
    ) 
            THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 
    END AS [has_definition]
FROM dbo.database_list AS d;
```

I don't think you'll need the distinct unless you really have duplicates in `dbo.database_list`.

Also please don't use `'single quotes'` for aliases - this syntax is deprecated, you should use `[square brackets]` instead.

Comment: Is there a way to doing this by joining 3 tables? I thought we could but couldnt wrap my head around the logic

Comment: Not sure I understand. Can't you add more `EXISTS` clauses? You'll need to add information to the question about these other tables and how they're related in order to get any useful input.

Answer (score 2):

I'd change it to use `EXISTS(SELECT * ....) OR EXISTS(SELECT * ....)` rather than the `SELECT(MAX)` business but apart from that looks OK to me.

SQL Server will probably show a plan with a concatenation operator that short circuits the `OR` as per [my tests here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5543985/73226). I also found that it would test the cheaper one to evaluate first in this case irrespective of order of the clauses.