# Is "OR" in SQL Server short-circuiting?

Tags: performance, sql-server-2005, boolean-logic, short-circuiting

Is the "OR" comparaison work like vb.
I mean if he check each or if the first one is false

like

```
DECLARE @var1 bit;
SET @var1=1
DECLARE @var2 bit;
SET @var2=1

(@var1=1 or @var2=1)
AND ...
```

So, @var is equal to 1, we dont need to check var2, but did sql server will do the check?

Its about optimisation of a query (and memory of server)

tank you

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5333/logical-operators-or-and-in-condition-and-order-of-conditions-in-where

Comment: VB's `Or` is actually **not** short-circuiting and *will* evaluate both conditionals. Compare with `OrElse` in VB. The only time the short-circuiting (or not) *really* matters *in terms of semantics*  is when side-effects, including Exceptions, are allowed in conditionals, and that is another question: "Does SQL Server allow side-effects in conditionals?"

Comment: @pst: Though the reason why OP wants short-circuiting is for performance, which is a valid non-side-effect-related reason :)

Comment: @mellamokb Yeah, I am avoiding responding to that desire entirely ;-)

Comment: tank you for your answers. it was really helpful. mostly to remember me dba.stackexchange (my fault).

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server Conditional Flow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5542927/sql-server-conditional-flow)

Answer (score 2):

For the most part, yes, SQL Server does use short-circuiting for AND and OR statements, but sometimes the operations do not happen in the order you would expect. This is easy enough to test via the following:

```
SELECT '"Divide By Zero" error' AS [test] WHERE (1 / 0 = 1)

SELECT 'NO "Divide By Zero" error' AS [test] WHERE (1 = 1) OR (1 / 0 = 1)
```

You can find a more in-depth analysis here, by Gianluca Sartori: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/71950/

Answer (score 0):

From [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/724305/add-support-for-and-then-and-or-else-logical-operators-in-tsql):

Thanks for your feedback. The logical operators that we support in SQL Server today is those specified in ANSI SQL standards and supported by pretty much every database system. We don't plan to extend it to support more unconventional logical operators. If you want to conditionally evaluate expressions then use a CASE expression instead in SQL Server like:

where case
     when  then (select 1 where )
     when  then (select 2 where )
     ...
     end = 1

The CASE expression guarantees that the WHEN/THEN clauses is evaluated in order.