# Does MySQL run all WHERE conditions if first is false

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

If you preform an `if` in PHP it will stop the conditions after the first false in the if-statement.

Has MySQL the same behavior in its where condition?

Suppose I have a query:

```
SELECT id FROM table_name WHERE row = value AND EXISTS(...)
```

Will the `EXISTS` statement be executed if `row = value` is `false`?

Comment: [this input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5542927/sql-server-conditional-flow) might give you answers on your question.

Comment: You can create a [Query Execution Plan](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/execution-plan-information.html) to get the specific answer for your particular query

Comment: In SQL, in general, you're telling the system "what you want", not "how to do it" - and one of the things you don't tend to get control over is what order it performs individual tasks in.

Answer (score 1):

There is no guarantee that the where conditions will be examined in the same order as they appear in the query. The execution plan will give you the answer,try

`EXPLAIN SELECT id FROM table_name WHERE row = value AND EXISTS(...)`

The plan may also vary depending on the table's statistics.