# why does sql server execute the second statement redundantly?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have the following which throws an error if the table Tru.Repo does not exist:

```
IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'Tru' AND TABLE_NAME = 'Repo')) OR 
   (NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Tru.Repo WHERE RepoName = 'Tru.Repo'))
BEGIN
    print('in')
END
```

but I would expect that if Tru.Repo does not exist, the first statement is true so why does it then execute the second statement? Is there anyway of getting around this using a single IF block?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5542927/sql-server-conditional-flow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

T-SQL is interpreted, so it'll want to make sure everything is valid first. You could solve it with dynamic SQL, but that's quite messy.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not that the second statement is *executed*.  The "problem" is that the entire statement is compiled before it is run.

So, the second statement is compiled.  And, you get a compilation error when the table doesn't exist.

Here is an approach to solving this problem:

```
IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'Tru' AND TABLE_NAME = 'Repo'))
BEGIN
    print('in')
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    declare @retval int = 0;
    exec sp_execute_sql N'SELECT @retval = 1 FROM Tru.Repo WHERE RepoName = ''Tru.Repo''',
                        N'@retval int output', @retval = @retval;
    if @retval = 0
    BEGIN
        print('in')
    END
END;
```